# SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService

Tags: java, linux, selenium

I'm using:

- Java 1.8
- Selenium 3.5.0
- Selenium Standalone Server 3.5.0
- OS for selenium hub - RHEL 7
- Geckodriver 18
- Firefox 55

I have an error:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService
    Build info: version: '3.5.0', revision: '8def36e068', time: '2017-08-10T23:00:22.093Z'
    System info: host: 'NC9128105064', ip: '9.128.105.64', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$24(ProtocolHandshake.java:360)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:363)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:137)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:641)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:254)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:174)
        at Utils.BrowserDriver.ff(BrowserDriver.java:66)
        at TestCases.Category.LogInCreateCategory.logIn(LogInCreateCategory.java:29)
        at TestCases.TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:82)
```

Code for chosing firefox:

```
            public static WebDriver ff() {

            File firefoxfile = new File(PropertyReader.getProperty("firefox"));
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", firefoxfile.getPath());

            WebDriver wd = null;//new RemoteWebDriver(dc);

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://" + TestRunner.SELENIUM_HUB + ":4444/wd/hub");
                FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
                // set something on the profile...
                DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
                //dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, fp);

                wd = new RemoteWebDriver(url, dc);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return wd;
    }
```

I think that something is wrong with the path to the geckodriver on Linux. I tried couple options like:

- `/drivers/geckodriver`
- `drivers/geckodriver`
- `root/drivers/geckodriver`
  but with no success

The `pwd` in dir with geckodriver on Linux gives me: 
`/root/drivers`

Answer (score 0):

please update geckodriver to the latest version.

```
File firefoxfile = new File(PropertyReader.getProperty("C://users//geckodriver.exe"));
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", firefoxfile.getPath());
```

Comment: I have geckodriver in version 18 so it is the newest. Also it has to run on Linux so the path has to be in linux style.

Comment: are you able to run atleast one scenario before this error occured ?

Comment: No, all tests are skipped.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and resolved it by setting the system property to **geckodriver.exe** path as given below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\tech2\\selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Set the property before instantiating the driver.

I found the solution [here](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/launching-firefox-browser-with-geckodriver-selenium-3). The issue seems specific to selenium 3.x+.